# why does it not follow the if statement

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
package com.example.firstapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.firstapplication.MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        if (EXTRA_MESSAGE.equals ("h")) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText(message);
            ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
            layout.addView(textView);
        }else {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(4);
            textView.setText(message);
            ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
            layout.addView(textView);
        }
    }
    }
```

if i type in h on my thing the output should be h in size 40 font and it should work only for h, but when is type in h or anything else it comes out in size 4, help, what do i do

Comment: You're checking whether `EXTRA_MESSAGE` equals "h". Are you sure you didn't meant to check `message`? Fundamentally we've no idea what `EXTRA_MESSAGE` is, or what that has to do with the "thing" you type `h` into. Also note that you're testing all of this on *creation* - are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a more minimal example, and include all relevant code.

Comment: I think instead of EXTRA_MESSAGE, do you want to check with message string?

Comment: He is also importing EXTRA_MESSAGE, which in this case is irrelevant because he has already passed the variable with intent, just your message with something like **String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");**

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of EXTRA_MESSAGE, do you want to check with message string?

Else you can use the debug mode in Android Studio to know what variables contains.